# Keeping track of sessions in client-server conversations (desktop client, webservices-based PHP app)

Tags: php, rest, web-services, session

My question is more architectural than actually about a specific language related problem.

I am currently in the design phase of a new application. Several clients make HTTP requests to a central web application, that *must* be coded in PHP. I can implement the services, but I am facing a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I need to keep track of the "sessions" the client creates. For that, when the user presses a button it makes a request that logs the session init in the database. Then there are several circumstances that should make the server mark the session as finished:

1. The user ends the task, which must be repeated several times
2. The user goes away for a certain amount of time
3. The user loses the connection

I am planning to handle number 2 from the client side. If there is no task execution for a certain amount of time, the client sends an "end session, execution not finished" request. The number 1 can be handled from client side too, when the number of executions is finished, then you send an "end session, execution finished" request. With which I have problems is with the number 3, how can I detect that the user has lost the connection from the server side in a timely manner?

I can't create cron jobs and, if I simulate them, it may be too late when the next request comes for closing the unfinished session. Any hint on how to approach this problem?

I was also thinking about websockets, but is that advisable when connecting from a desktop application to a server?. My access to the server is very limited, as I can't do any administration tasks on it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: when I say sessions, I am not referring to PHP sessions but to "sets of operations" that are done in the client and that the server must register.

Answer (score 0):

What You mean under "loses the connection"? We can tell about connection when it is real-time communication. If we are talking about webapp user doing action, waiting some time and doing another action. So we can not say user loses connection. You can check PHP session and if it is expired You can log out user (if users need to log in).

Comment: I mean, for example, that WiFi connectivity is lost from the computer and the computer stops being able to do requests to the server. These are different from PHP Sessions (as a computer should be able to handle multiple sessions within the same IP and ideally should not be storing cookies like the PHP SESSID). They are just "sets of operations"

Comment: You can't check user connection. If user close browser after click button (run script) You don't know that, because script is executing by server. The only idea I have is to do script with infinity loop. This script could check database after every X second and if there is user who do no action for Y time then send "end session" to database.

Comment: It is not a browser, it is a desktop application that runs towards the services inside a web server. I can control if the user closes the application.

Comment: It is meanless. Your desktop app makes HTTP request and when its fully sent then rest of work is done by server. If You want to check is user connected to server You need real-time communication - use sockets.
If no sockets - use infinity loop in script to checking database's logs. That's all.

Comment: That is why I talked about websockets. That said, you could implement that also with a ping request and timeouts. So no, no bidirectional communication is really needed if it wasn't because I have to do it in PHP and I have no way to really implement a timeout on the server side, unless I am missing something.